# How to query for a particular string under a list of string and retrieve the value

Tags: python, regex, file, full-text-search

Given a data file, I need to query for a particular value under a given a list and extract the value associated with that

Say my data file looks like

```
Surface name: wing

Total CL    (   86%):    0.994313 | Pressure (  100%):    0.994348 | Friction (    0%):   -0.000035 | Momentum (    0%):    0.000000

Surface name: body

Total CL    (    1%):    0.018554 | Pressure (   99%):    0.018535 | Friction (    0%):    0.000019 | Momentum (    0%):    0.000000
```

I need to query for the value of `Total CL` under each surface name and extract the value of that. I need the final output as

```
Surface name  Total CL
wing           0.9943
body           0.0185
```

My rather novice attempt was to use regex expression for querying for the value of `Total CL` as follows

```py
import os
import re
import shutil

SurfaceList=[wing,body]
CL=[]

# I need to query for Total CL for each of the elements of the list

regexp1=re.compile(r'Total CL: .*?([0-9.-]+)')
for surface in SurfaceList:
   with open(file) as f:
        for line in f:
            match1 = regexp1.match(line)
            if (match1):
                CL.append(match2.group(1))
```

However this only queries for the first instance of the occurrence and stops further queries, I am unable to go to the further elements of the list.

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of errors in your code:

- What are `wing` and `body`? Did you define such variables elsewhere?
- What is `match2`? Did you mean `match1`?
- `re.match` is not the function that you're searching for, because it looks for an *exact* match. `re.search` instead is the right one.
- Your regex is wrong! Why do you use the colons after `Total CL` if you don't have them in your file? Moreover, you're searching for the first number coming after it, but the first number is the percentage! You should use instead something like `^Total CL.*?([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b(?!%))`, where `\b` is the word boundary and `(?!%)` means not followed by `%`.

I believe this is what you need:

```py
regexp1 = re.compile(r'^Surface name:[ \t]+(\w+)')
regexp2 = re.compile(r'^Total CL.*?([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b(?!%))')
with open(file) as f :
    surface = None
    for line in f :
        src1 = regexp1.search(line)
        if src1 :
            surface = src1.group(1)
        elif surface in SurfaceList :
            src2 = regexp2.search(line)
            if src2 :
                CL.append((surface, src2.group(1)))
print(CL)
#[('wing', '0.994313'), ('body', '0.018554')]
```

Or, if you can open your file with a single `read` call, you can use `re.findall`:

```py
with open(file) as f :
    whole_text = f.read()
CL = re.findall(r'(?m)^Surface name:[ \t]+(\w+)\s+^Total CL.*?([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\b(?!%))', whole_text)
print(CL)
#[('wing', '0.994313'), ('body', '0.018554')]
```

Comment: You're welcome! Please consider [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978) one of the answers, if they helped you.

Answer (score 1):

You can derive the surface names from the file.

The value you want to extract is the first sequence of characters between : (colon) and | (pipe) on lines that start with 'Total CL'

Therefore:

```
import re

result: dict[str, float|str] = {'Surface name': 'Total CL'}
surface = None
pattern = re.compile(r'(?<=\:).+?(?=\|)')

with open('/Volumes/G-Drive/data.txt') as data:
    for line in map(str.strip, data):
        if line.startswith('Surface'):
            surface = line.split()[-1]
        elif surface and line.startswith('Total CL'):
            result[surface] = float(pattern.findall(line)[0])

for k, v in result.items():
    print(f'{k:<14}{v}')
```

**Output:**

```
Surface name Total CL
wing         0.994313
body         0.018554
```